# VSTO ClickOnce Deployment config values

Tags: .net, ms-word, installation, vsto

I have created a VSTO Add-in in word that would read form fields and save them to a document in Local folder.

During development, I added an app.config so that we can configure the output folder.

Now that we want to promote it to QA and other environments. The question I have is how do we make this configurable?

Clickonce creates a manifest file and application files but unlike other .net apps, it doesnt have app.config file in publish folder.

I am thinking if the only way is to do a windows installer setup project and possibly add this Outputfolder as a registry entry and reference this registry entry in code?

When we install VSTO add-in where does it install the files?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ClickOnce installs VSTO Add-Ins to an obfuscated folder under %localappdata%\Apps\2.0. Thus you don't have the ability to change things in app.config that way.

One option, and I suspect this is possible but don't know for sure, is to put your app.config in a network folder and pull it in at runtime.

Another is to create an entirely separate configuration outside of app.config. One way to do this that is pretty easy is to create classes for the fields you want to store, avoid non-nullable types (e.g. use bool? instead of bool), and add [Serializable] to each class. Then use `XmlSerializer.Serialize` to write it out to a file and `XmlSerializer.Deserialize` to read it. You could probably use JSON serialization as well.